# How can there be consensus once the tangle is too large for a single iri node to track?

Tags: scalability, consensus

At one point, the tangle might grow so large or fast that a single iri node can't be aware of all transactions happening. How to have consensus about address balances without iri nodes trusting each other?
How to create snapshots if there's no single node that sees the entire tangle?

Answer (score 3):

A single IOTA node can already handle around 1000 transactions per second, this is quite a bit but probably not enough in the future. Once this becomes an issue sharding can be a solution. This means that only a part of the tangle is handled by cluster of nodes that for example only handle transactions starting with the letter 'A'; Another cluster will be responsible for transactions starting with the letter 'B', etc. I think the IOTA team still has some time to solve this issue completely before it becomes an issue.

Comment: To add, sharding will not be based on arbitrary labels, but on economic activity. Tangles will naturally form subclusters.

Comment: I'd like to discuss this further, but I guess StackExchange is the wrong medium for that. I've started a thread on the forum: https://forum.iota.org/t/how-can-iota-scale-beyond-1000-tx-s/6392?u=brenzi

Comment: I'm puzzled with the digital coin era! I am a java programmer for 10 years now, seen IOTA code at GitHub, and wonder how such a project is worth $10,336,128,082!!! OMG! The world is going nuts!!!

Comment: Where does the 1000 tx/s number come from? Please put a link in the answer.

Comment: @wuerg this number is based on bandwidth considerations see e.g. this [question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/665/estimation-of-network-traffic-for-a-full-node?noredirect=1&lq=1)