# Estimation of network traffic for a Full Node

Tags: iri-node

## Background

Full nodes allow to get an complete view on the state of the Tangle (after a snapshot) in order to verify transactions, and to append new transactions to the Tangle.

Therefore, full nodes have two major tasks:

1. Receiving and propagating transactions to neighbours
2. Filtering out incoming transactions that are invalid because they didn't provide enough Proof-of-Work (by checking the nonces of the transactions)

The first task is network-intensive, the second task is rather CPU-intensive.

## Assumptions for estimating the network traffic

For calculating the network traffic accruing for a full node I assumed:

- 1650 bytes for a single transaction
- 1000 global Tangle transactions per second
- 5 active neighbors for the full node under investigation
- Each transaction will be either (a) received from, or (b) send to each neighbor 
   (which is the optimized version of pure flooding)

## Estimation of the accruing network traffic

Based on these assumptions, the (aggregated ingoing and outgoing) network traffic of a full node can be estimated as follows:

- **663.85 GB per day** (= 1650*1000*(60*60*24)*5 bytes)
- = **27.66 GB per hour**
- = **472.07 MB per min**
- = **7.87 MB per sec**
- = **62.94 Mbit per sec**

## Questions

- Is this a valid estimate for n=1000 transactions per second, are the assumptions legit, or am I getting something wrong?
- Are there any sources available to read more on the scalability, any simulation results?

Comment: Seems legit, but I'm not sure about the transaction size, won't compression make those smaller?
In any case, those numbers are manageable by current hardware on decent connections; remote locations could be in trouble.

Comment: Did you take into account that some transactions can contain up to 3.5K of payload? See this answer for details https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/171/607

Comment: You may want to have a look here. This site features and visualizes a lot of interesting data and load statistics. https://iota.lukaseder.de/load.html

Comment: I am still learning so hoping to be corrected or confirmed by someone more learned, but to your first question - if the global TPS=1000 AFAIK you and your neighbors would only be seeing a fraction of that. If you and your neighbors are globally dispersed, the transaction set seen by each should be different. There is a high chance of overlap if all are geographically close. The question then becomes what TPS figure to use. I believe one of the return values from the getNeighbors API - most probably numberOfAllTransactions. This value is cumulative so use the difference between API calls.

Comment: @lanu-moe I have similar question to yours, but about estimation of max possible tx/second at the moment. Check this out https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/what-is-the-max-possible-transactions-second-rate-in-iota

Answer (score 5):

My current network traffic (24h) with 3 neighbors:
IN: 860MB
OUT: 700MB

Comment: Thanks! In my question above I assumed **1000 transactions/sec and 5 neighbors**. Currently we are experiencing [1 to 2 transactions per second](https://thetangle.org/live). So scaling down the estimate to **1.5 transactions/sec and 3 neighbors**, the calculated 663.85 GB per day (aggregated in and out traffic) result in `663.85 * 1024 * (1.5/1000) * (3/5) = 611.80 MB`. This is about 40% of the measured 1560 MB. Given the uncertainty regarding the transactions, the calculation seems to roughly fit. But as the overhead of TCP/UPD is pretty low, I'm still wondering about further crucial factors?