# What is the max possible transactions/second rate in IOTA?

Tags: transaction, iota-network, proof-of-work

Did anyone calculate the max amount of transactions per second which is possible in IOTA?

As far as I understand the transactions rate is only limited by network's bandwidth of full nodes.
Let's assume that all full nodes have 10 megabit per second (actulally it's very generous assumption).
The size of a transaction a node needs to pass to another node is 1650 bytes. So we have:

> 10,000,000 / (1,650 * 8) = 757.5757575757576

So the maximum possible transactions per second will be around 750 transactions per second (in reality I think this number will be much
smaller as nodes will send duplicate transactions to each other, but let's forget about this here).

Am I correct? Did I miss something?

Comment: Gladly, I went ahead

Comment: The minimum standard in a datacenter (cheap VPS, ~10 USD/month) is 100 mbit/s. Also, these nodes work in parallel.

Comment: Hmm, can you give me an example of such data center? DigitalOcean for example provides 2TB per month for 10$ (check here https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/#droplet). 2TB per month is around 6.2 Mb/s (assuming that the load is constantly high). Of course a full node owner can provide 100 Mbit/s for bigger price, but I'm talking about an average full node.

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't matter that nodes work in parallel. Still EVERY SINGLE node in the network have to receive ALL transactions created in
the system. If the transactions rate in the system is 1000 tx/sec for example and the node can receive only 500 tx/sec, then this
node will fall behind, will be out of sync and you won't be able to use it anymore. So the transaction rate is limited by the bandwidth
the single node can provide.

Comment: @daniel-f Please, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Swarm nodes don't have to receive everything. It's enough for a segment to be able to confirm its transactions.

Comment: @daniel-f Swarm nodes don't exist at the moment and nobody knows how they will be implemented. So we can't take them into consideration.

Comment: Hmm. Someone who gave me a neighbor address told me that it was a swarm node so that I should not expect too much from that node.

Comment: https://contabo.com/?show=vps 100 mbit/s (9 EUR/Month). Also data rates will increase in the future.

Comment: https://www.scaleway.com/pricing/ 300mbit/s without transfer limit for 12€. This server is actually used for full nodes according to the #fullnodes slack channel